# Can't use manually downloaded svn binaries

Tags: svn, ubuntu, environment-variables, osx-mavericks

I am trying to use my downloaded version of svn. However, it doesn't work even though I exported the environment variable of svn into PATH. When I run `which svn` it still shows `/usr/bin/svn` . Here this is `.bash_profile` file looks like;

```
export PATH="/usr/local/dev/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

export SVN_HOME=/usr/local/dev/subversion-1.6
export PATH=$PATH:$SVN_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Are the executables in `/usr/local/dev/git/bin` `a+x`? Did you `source` your `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:$SVN_HOME/bin
```

… adds the subversion directory *after* the existing directories on your `PATH`. If you want it to come *before* `/usr/bin`, you have to write it that way:

```
 export PATH=$SVN_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

---

If this isn't obvious, try `echo $PATH` on the shell. You'll see that the order looks like this:

- `/usr/local/dev/git/bin`
- `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/bin`
- `/usr/local/sbin`
- (whatever the default system `$PATH` is)
- `/usr/local/dev/subversion-1.6/bin`

So the first `svn` on your PATH is still going to be the one in `/usr/bin`.

The `-a` flag to `which` can also be helpful here:

```
$ which -a svn
/usr/bin/svn
/usr/local/dev/subversion-1.6/bin/svn
```

The first one is the one that gets run.

Comment: That works! I first thought that it overrides the first svn directory. However, thanks a lot.